# Invalid data handling over TCP socket

Tags: tcp

I have a GUI application that sends/recv over tcp to a server.

Sometimes, we get junk data while doing a tcp recv from the server. While reading these nulls or invalid data, the client application crashes sometimes.

Is there a good way to validate this data? - other than catching this exception.

I dont want the GUI application to crash because of bad data sent by the server.

Comment: Language? Framework? Type/structure of data? Type of Error? Why not just catch that exception? -- this is lacking so much.

Answer (score 0):

TCP has a checksum that it uses to validate the data received; that is done by the operating system (or sometimes the network hardware, if you have nice hardware). If the contents are not correct, with a *very high* probability, the data that was sent was incorrect. I just state that because I'm not totally sure that you were aware of this fact.

If you need to validate the data, you will have to validate the data. Write a function that parses your data, and returns a meaningful value only if there's meaningful data. Make your GUI aware of this.

Your question is kind of self-answering... you can't say "I want to be fault-tolerant, but I don't want to care about faults" ("other than catching this exception"), and based on the lack of description of the data you'd expect, I'd say you don't really care about the form of the data.